# I Cannot run my code due to this error in vscode. I cannot understand the error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I Cannot run my code due to this error in vs code. I cannot understand the error.  I have attached the image link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FVJm.png

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste code as text into the question, also copy the error message as text.

Comment: I can not search the web for your error, as it has been turned into a picture.

Comment: I think you have not saved your source file. As a result the file you are trying to compile is empty. Your linker fails to find `int main()` or `WinMain()`

Comment: why don't you search SO for this error, you are not the first, every few months we get a wave of this error, is it the start of a new school trimester

Comment: Anybody know how to apply a clue hammer to the vscode folks, to get them to, like *give the user a helpful warning* if they try to hit the Run button without saving?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In fairness, this is probably one of those cases where the image actually *is* useful.  Several people got the clue from the OP's image that the code hadn't been saved, a detail which would likely not have showed up if the OP had just pasted the text of the error message.

Comment: @SteveSummit I understood that they guessed file is not saved because of the error message (and mingw+VSCode default behaviours), not because of anything on the screen. I don't see any indication that file is modified on this screen. And, as it is, this question is not useful to anyone in the future - if I try to duckduckgo `Undefined reference to 'WinMain'`, I will not find this question or its answers.

Comment: dup of: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing happening here due to *WinMain* error  is The compiler is not getting any instruction from where to start executing the code (This happens when we don't have a main() function in the program) As Your program already has the int main() function but it is clearly seen that you have not saved your file before Compiling so,

1. **You Should Save your file before running/compiling it** by`Ctrl-S`
2. **also, You can change the settings of the Code runner to Save on Run so you won't have to save your code again and again**

Answer (score 1):

Save your file by pressing `ctrl+S` and then run it again.

Comment: That is a good finding, but not the root cause of the problem. The linker looks for `WinMain`, not `main`.

Comment: Doesn't the mingw linker look for WinMain when it can't find main() then error out if that does not exist?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I have faced the same issue in the past and it was resolved by saving the file.